# Running wifi adb on android 10 device

Tags: android, kotlin

Can I run wireless debugging on android 10 device for android development on android studio?

I have tried to solve this problem but I stuck...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be officially supported you need Android 11+.

> Android 11 and higher supports deploying and debugging your app
> wirelessly from your workstation using Android Debug Bridge (adb). For
> example, you can deploy your debuggable app to multiple remote devices
> without physically connecting your device via USB. This eliminates the
> need to deal with common USB connection issues, such as driver
> installation.

To connect a device running Android 10 or lower, follow these initial steps over USB:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect device_ip_address:5555
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your phone to PC over USB cable.
2. Then go to Developer options and on USB Debugging. (Make sure your PC and phone are connected to the same Wi-fi network or router).
3. Now open Terminal from Android Studio or regular cmd.
4. Check android studio connected over usb fine. Now in terminal or cmd type `adb tcpip 5555`. If shown your something your device id (just not error) then type `adb connect your_phone_ip` and press enter. Your phone will be connected.
5. Now disconnect USB cable. It will still be connected wirelessly.

Note: It will be disconnected if your phone go sleep mode. (I faced it) so set display sleep time up you need.

Here I give special tricks. if disconnect or next time you want to connect then you do it for avoid again connect usb. go to your phone developer option. go to usb configuration select file transfer and again, select usb media transfer mode
now terminal commond adb connect phone_ip if show error first commond adb tcpip 5555 and then second commond adb connect phone_ip
so that no need again 1st need usb cable. i test it. my phone work fine. only problem when phon go sleep mode then disconnected. oh sorry, not forget when usb connect then android studio send to phone allow request prompt. so 1st checkbox and then allow so that all necessary request granted.